# Spring - Post parameters without form

Tags: spring, post

I'm writing a CRUD application in Spring and I need to navigate to the "details" page from the "list of items" page.
Currently I'm using anchors and appending the item's id to the URL, i.e. something like

http://hostname/edit/{itemId}

But the ids can be quite long and there could be other parameters so the URL is bound to be something long.

The obvious solution (for me at least) would be to use POST instead of GET, but I was wondering if it's possible to post data without using forms or if there is another mechanism in Spring to pass data to the controller?

Comment: What do you mean to post data without using forms? You can make post request in controller. And you can pass data to controller using `@RequestBody` and send java object to controller.

Comment: From the page, instead of clicking on a link that contains the parameters in the URL (which is a GET), I want to POST the parameters. Usually you would do that using a form.

Answer (score 1):

You could send an Ajax request from js and send your data in a POST body.
From HTML you can only send POST request from a form.

Comment: Do I need 3rd party libraries to use AJAX or can I do it in plain JS?

Comment: Jquery or other library make it more easier to make Ajax call but you can do it in plain JS

Answer (score 0):

If your question is can you make post requests with parameters, the answer is yes. You can make post request handler in controller just as any other type of request, you can use `@PathVariable` and `@PathParam` for parameters, or you can work with java objects (using jackson dependancy) and attach the object to request or having object as a response with `@RequestBody` or `@ResponseBody`. Here is the example:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/test/{param}", method={RequestMethod.POST})
public int test(@PathVariable(name = "param") int param) throws SQLException{

    return param;

}
```

Comment: I already know that I can build a controller like that. My question is how to call the controller from the page without using an HTML form.

Comment: Do you use Angularjs?